# A symmetric iid process

Tags: distributions, density-function, independence, iid, symmetry

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be an iid process with $X_i$ having a symmetric distribution around $0$. Then can I always write
$$X_1 - \alpha X_{t-1}-\alpha^2 X_{t-2}-\cdots \stackrel{iid}{=} X_1 + |\alpha| X_{t-1}+|\alpha|^2 X_{t-2}+\cdots?$$

I think so, as $X_i\stackrel{iid}{=}-X_i$ and, thus, I just have to consider the magnitude of $\alpha$, the sign of it will be taken care of by $X_i$'s.

Comment: Hi: Unfortunately, no. What you wrote about the iid equivalence is true but the absolute value of $|X|_{i}$ does not have the same distribution as the $X_{i}$ so you have a different model if you take the absolute value of the $X_{i}$. I assume that there is some output $Y_{t}$ and you are trying to estimate $\alpha$ ? If so, google for exponential smoothing because that is what that model is called. Actually it's the negative of exponential smoothing in which case it's really  a koyck distributed lag model with $\beta = -1$ so google for that instead.

Comment: Hello @mlofton, I have not taken the absolute value of $X_i$, rather considered only the absolute value of the scalar $\alpha$.

Comment: My fault. You are correct. It was late and I missed that. Note though ( and I'm not sure if this is the case ).   if you are estimating some response, say $Y_{t}$ which is equal to say $X_{1} - \alpha * X_{t-1} - \alpha^2 X_{t-2} + \ldots $, then, if you want to use  $|\alpha|$ instead of $\alpha$, then that is equivalent to assuming that $\alpha$ is positive so you are going to need an extra coefficient $\beta$ to multiply the  expression that uses the absolute value.  If you are not estimating a response, then  I was totally wrong and just made things more confusing.

Comment: If you are estimating a model with a response, then $\alpha$ needs to be restricted to be 0 and 1 and check out what I said previously about the koyck distributed lag because it allows for the addition of the extra parameter $\beta$. If not, then apologies for all the noise.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @mlofton! However, I am not estimating anything and my work is nowhere related to regression. What I asked in the question is my question.

Comment: gotcha. then my apologies for noise. your statement about the IID relation is absolutely correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following facts

1. If $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of symmetric around zero random variables and for all $i\geqslant 1$, $a_i$ is a (deterministic) element of $\{-1,1\}$, then the sequences $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ and $\left(a_iX_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ have the same distribution.

   To see this, it suffices to prove that for all $n$, the vectors $\left(X_i\right)_{i= 1}^n$ and $\left(a_iX_i\right)_{i= 1}^n$ have the same distribution, which can be done by considering the characteristic functions. These ones can be written as a product (by independence), and the factors are equal, by the symmetry around zero.
2. If two sequences $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ and $\left(Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ have the same distribution and $f\colon \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\to\mathbb R$ is a measurable function (where $\mathbb R^N$ is endowed with the product $\sigma$-algebra, then $f\left( \left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}   \right)$ and $f\left( \left(Y_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}   \right)$ have the same distribution.